# Coding of '\xa1' in Perl

Tags: perl

I want to process a txt file using perl. I have succeeded in using this perl code to process wikipedia txt file before, so it is correct. But when I run the perl code, there appears an error:

```
utf8 "\xA1" does not map to Unicode at xxx
```

I check the txt file. There is \xA1 characters in it. I tried to remove those "\xA1" with RegEx `s/(\xa1)+//g;` but failed.

So what is the problem and how can I solve this?

Comment: What's the encoding of the text file?

Comment: It seems to be Utf-8. I read it as 'utf-8' in my perl code.

Comment: `\xA1` simply is not Unicode. Latin-1 has the inverted exclamation mark `¡` under this byte. This character is available in Unicode as `U+00A1` and is encoded in UTF-8 as `\xC2\xA1`

Comment: It's not UTF-8, or at least not valid UTF-8, according to the only information you gave us.

Comment: How can I get rid of it though?

Comment: You get rid of the problem by using the correct encoding. You're telling Perl your file is UTF-8, but it's not.

Comment: @ikegami Thank you. I solve the problem. But I am still not clear. Why does perl need to map the character to Unicode as the error states?

Comment: @ikegami All right. As a new coder, coding problems always bother me.

Comment: @Denzel, Because you explicitly asked it to do so by using `binmode( IN,  ':utf8' );`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, I revise my code. I use

```
binmode( IN,  ':stdio' );
```

instead of

```
binmode( IN,  ':utf8' );
```

and it works.

Comment: `binmode( IN,  ':encoding(iso-latin-1)' );` is what you should be using, then (which is basically doing nothing at all).